# Loopback 4 how to override the built-un User model

Tags: node.js, loopback, loopback4

I'm a beginner on loopback 4. I'm trying to secure my REST API with @loopback/authentication-jwt.

I would like to add some columns on User built-in model but i don't know why... I have not found any documentation about that.

Can you help me please ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Patrick, you can create your own user model by using the `lb4 model` command in the terminal and define the properties there. After adding the model you need to create the repository, so that it can read/write to the database.

Finally create a controller to expose the REST API. I recommend you follow the step by step on Loopback 4 [tutorials page](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Tutorials.html)

The basic flow is:-

1. Create model
2. Create repository
3. Create controller

Then API is ready.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The `User` model already exists in the `authentication-jwt` package.